# Open source Objective C (or C/C++) library for audio to H.323?

Tags: iphone, c++, c, ios, h.323

I'm building a voip app for iOS devices using the H.323 protocol and was wondering if there any libraries in Objective C (or C/C++) that let me convert my audio to H.323

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only 2 OpenSource H.323 libraries both C++: [H323Plus](http://www.h323plus.org/) and [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/). And then there is the commercial Radvision SDK, which is done in C as far as I know.